# Cordova sqlite plugin not creating database

Tags: sqlite, cordova

I am new to this, any examples of projects you have done?

this is my code:

this throws errors when accessing data

```
function createDB(){
    mui.alert('create');
        db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: 'my.db', location: 'default'}, requestSQL('User'), errorcb);
        mui.alert('pase');
        function successcb(){
            db.transaction(function(tx) {
              tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MyTable');
              tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE MyTable (SampleColumn)');
              mui.alert('cree tabla');
              tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (?)', ['test-value'], function(tx, resultSet) {
                mui.alert('resultSet.insertId: ' + resultSet.insertId);
                mui.alert('resultSet.rowsAffected: ' + resultSet.rowsAffected);
              }, function(tx, error) {
                mui.alert('INSERT error: ' + error.message);
              });
            }, function(error) {
              mui.alert('transaction error: ' + error.message);
            }, function() {
              mui.alert('transaction ok');
            });
        }
        function errorcb(error){
            mui.alert('SELECT error: ' + error.message);
        }

        db.executeSql("SELECT SampleColumn FROM MyTable", [], function (resultSet) {
          mui.alert('got stringlength: ' + resultSet.rows.item(0).SampleColumn);
        }, function(error) {
          mui.alert('SELECT error: ' + error.message);
        });
}
```

Comment: What errors is it throwing?

Comment: Please send us the error message not just "help" spamming.